# Date column with value '-' in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a date column in data bricks, which has a value '-' for 1 record. I am unable to either filter it out or select this row. How can i use this value '-' in where clause?

I have tried

```
spark_df_2023_fil=spark_df_2023.filter(spark_df_2023["navdt"] == '-')
spark_df_2023_fil=spark_df_2023.filter(spark_df_2023["navdt"] != '-')
```

but both these give me 0 records.

Comment: what's the data type of `navdt`? `"-"` seems to be a string -- databricks might be showing nulls as `-` internally as well. try filtering for `None` for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me...I hope this is what you were trying ?

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import datetime
schema = StructType([StructField("navdt", StringType(), True)])
l = [("2024-03-01",),('-',)]
spark_df_2023 = spark.createDataFrame(l, schema)
display(spark_df_2023)
df = spark_df_2023.filter(spark_df_2023.navdt != '-')
display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: in your dataframe , isnt the datatype of navdt string ?  you have used 'StringType()'. In my case its data type is DATE

Comment: yes correct, but can you please check the type on your dataframes ? I just was not able to create a dataframe with date column with a value as '-'

Comment: yes, thats the issue.  It seems to be some parsing issue with this value. Ideally a DATE field cant have '-' as value.  I am creating spark dataframe from underlying data , which has this '-' value. Now I dont know whats the actual value or if its just showing as '-'....  I am not sure how to handle this record ?

Comment: pls share how your source data looks like - are you directly reading into spark ? or are you reading as string, converting somewhere - pandas coming up somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for leading or trailing whitespaces? use this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark_df_2023.filter(f.trim(spark_df_2023["navdt"]) == '-')
```